# How to pass data from one view controller to the other SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, view, segue

I am making an app where a table view with a search bar and scope bar has to segue to a detail view controller and that detail view controller has to display data based on which cell is selected. I have an array with structs set up to sort and search for the items. I need to keep this feature, I have another swift class for my detail view controller that I will put if/else statements into that deal with displaying the data based on what cell 
I select. What I need to know how to do is attach a variable to the cells and pass that variable to the detail view controller to use in my if/else statements so that I can display the data. If this is not the correct way to do this, please let me know.

Struct code

```
struct Booth {
    let category : String
    let name : String
}
```

Table view controller code

```
import UIKit

class BoothsTableViewController: UITableViewController {    

var booths = [Booth]()
var filteredBooths = [Booth]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //fill array with data
    self.booths = [Booth(category: "Tech", name: "Conference App"),
        Booth(category: "Tech", name: "Space Shooter"),
        Booth(category: "Tech", name: "RollABall"),
        Booth(category: "Animation", name: "Sugar Hill City Model"),
        Booth(category: "Animation", name: "3D Sculpting 101"),
        Booth(category: "Animation", name: "HowTo - Texture"),
        Booth(category: "Science", name: "AP Biology for Dummies"),
        Booth(category: "Science", name: "Cells"),
        Booth(category: "Science", name: "Space")]

    //reload the table
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        return self.filteredBooths.count
    } else {
        return self.booths.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //ask for a reusable cell from the tableview, the tableview will create a new one if it doesn't have any
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    var boothsCheck : Booth
    // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Booth object from the appropriate array
    if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
        boothsCheck = filteredBooths[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        boothsCheck = booths[indexPath.row]
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = boothsCheck.name
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    self.filteredBooths = self.booths.filter({( Booth : Booth) -> Bool in
        var categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Booth.category == scope)
        var stringMatch = Booth.name.rangeOfString(searchText)
        return categoryMatch && (stringMatch != nil)
    })
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    let scopes = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
    let selectedScope = scopes[self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex] as String
    self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString, scope: selectedScope)
    return true
}

func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!,
    shouldReloadTableForSearchScope searchOption: Int) -> Bool {
        let scope = self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles as [String]
        self.filterContentForSearchText(self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.text, scope: scope[searchOption])
        return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("BoothDetail", sender: tableView)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "BoothDetail" {

        let BoothDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController


        if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let destinationTitle = self.filteredBooths[indexPath.row].name
            BoothDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle


    } else {

            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let destinationTitle = self.booths[indexPath.row].name
            BoothDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Segue code

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "BoothDetail" {

        let BoothDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController


        if sender as UITableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
                let indexPath = self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let destinationTitle = self.filteredBooths[indexPath.row].name
                BoothDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle        
        } else {            
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
                let destinationTitle = self.booths[indexPath.row].name
                BoothDetailViewController.title = destinationTitle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For instance, in your `BoothsTableViewController` create  variable holding the currently selected Booth, which you assign in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You can then pass this variable to the detail view controller in your `prepareForSegue` method.

Comment: Yes thank you, the thing is I do not know exactly how to pass it @Rick

Comment: Simply create a variable in the detail view as well, which you can set after you've created the `DetailViewController`, just like you do with the title.

Answer (score 0):

Create a member variable/object in detailViewController. Set this object in prepareforSegue in your current TableViewController. This way the detailViewController will have the cell object the user clicked.