# Incorrect array values when accessing an array from another class?

Tags: ios, arrays, class, swift, reduce

So I have one class:

```
class FoodListTable: UITableViewController
```

One property I set of this class is an array:

```
var calorieNumberArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

The reason I have this array is for different values based off if a row(s) is/are selected (using the tableView Checkmark accessibility type). I did some tests and when a row(s) is/are selected, the array values are changing correctly. I also have a variable that finds the sum of the values in `calorieNumberArray`:

```
var calorieTotal: Float {
    return calorieNumberArray.reduce(0 as Float) { $0 + Float($1) }
}
```

I also have another class:

```
class Menu: Calculator // Calculator class is of type UIViewController
```

I transition from the `FoodListTable` class to the `Menu` class using a navigation bar.
In the ViewDidLoad method of the class `menu`, I try to access the values of the `calorieNumberArray` and `calorieTotal`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        let foodListTableAccess = FoodListTable()
        println(foodListTableAccess.calorieNumberArray)
        println(foodListTableAccess.calorieTotal)
```

And this is what shows up in the console:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] // calorieNumberArray
0.0 // calorieTotal
```

How can I access the `FoodListTable` class correctly from the `Menu` class so that the values of `calorieNumberArray` and `calorieTotal` stay the same and don't reset to their original values? Thank you!

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your FoodListTable class. You need to pass a reference to the existing instance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662256/how-to-pass-data-from-one-view-controller-to-the-other-swift for example

Comment: I read over that question and answer, and I kind of understand how I could pass the variable over. If possible, is there any way you could create an answer on how to pass over the variable in this scenario? I am new to programming so many parts of the other answer confuse me. Thank you @Paulw11

Comment: When you say you transition between the two using a menu bar, are you going "back" to the `Menu` class or forward?

Comment: I am going forward to the menu class @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `viewDidLoad` function in your `Menu` class is instantiating a new instance of `FoodListTable` and the variables in that new instance will have their initialised values.  You need to pass a reference to your existing instance.  You can do this in `prepareForSegue` in `FoodListTable`.

First, in your `Menu` class, add a new property of type `FoodListTable?` to receive the reference and then in `FoodListTable` add the following -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "yourSegueName" {   // Change to suit the name of the segue between the two 

        let menu = segue.destinationViewController as Menu
        menu.foodListTable=self;
    }
}
```

Now in your Menu instance you can just access self.foodListTable.

From an object-oriented design it would be better to create a data model object and create an instance of this object in `FoodTableViewController` and then pass this object around rather than the view controller itself - this way you are decoupling your 'model' from your 'view controller'